# run_local_server() on Google App Engine not working (errno98 Address already in use)

Tags: python-3.x, google-app-engine

I'm making a web application in App Engine using python37. I was using InstalledAppFlow running it locally to make an API request to a Google API, which made me login in a browser window to get the authorisation.

I've tried using the code that worked locally, but on the app engine environment it doesn't seem to be working. Also tried using a different way using an authorization_url, but that uses extra steps that I don't want (and didn't get that working either)

```py
flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_config(
                local_oauth_json,
                scopes=API_SCOPES
            )

flow.run_local_server()
credentials = flow.credentials

service = discovery.build(API_NAME, API_VERSION, credentials=credentials)

q = service.queries().getquery(queryId=text).execute()
```

I need an authorization method that won't need a local server and that can run on app engine.

Answer (score 0):

Per [GCP documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/oauth/), [Firebase Authentication](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/authenticating-users-firebase-appengine) is the easiest way to set up user authentication for a Google App Engine app.

Comment: I've tried this, but for the google sign in it has to be javascript based instead of python based, I guess? Everything works, except that I get a errno98 (address already in use) on running the local server to do the authentication.

Comment: can you add the console command(if any) and output with the error please?